# Django-Rest-Framework router register

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

i'm having a issue when i try to register more than 2 routers using Django-REST-FRAMEWORK. Please take a look on my example:

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from collaborativeAPP import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'get_vocab', views.VocabViewSet)
router.register(r'get_term', views.TermViewSet)
router.register(r'get_discipline', views.DisciplineViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns(
...
    url(r'^service/', include(router.urls))
)
```

**views.py**

```
class VocabViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vocab.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VocabSerializer

class TermViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Term.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TermSerializer

class DisciplineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vocab.objects.filter(kwdGroup=4)
    serializer_class = DisciplineSerializer
```

the result in my localhost is the following:

http://localhost:8000/service/

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "get_vocab": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/get_discipline/",
    "get_term": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/get_term/",
    "get_discipline": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/get_discipline/"
}
```

As you can see i have registered 3 routers expecting that they will display 3 urls for each methodname(`get_vocab`, `get_term`, `get_discipline`). The final result is  `get_discipline` is occuring two times and get_vocab url is missing.

Notice that for methods that uses different models it works fine, but in case of get_discipline and get_vocab they use the same model which will create this mess. Should i use a viewset for each model? If so, how can a define different methods in a viewset?

It should occur the following result:

```
 HTTP 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json
 Vary: Accept
 Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

 {
     "get_vocab": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/get_vocab/",
     "get_term": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/get_term/",
     "get_discipline": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/get_discipline/"
 }
```

What am i missing? I supposed that i could register as many routers as i want. It is supposed to have one router per model? Why doesn't seem to work for viewsets that share a same model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try explicitly adding a base_name to each registered viewset:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'vocabs', views.VocabViewSet, 'vocabs')
router.register(r'terms', views.TermViewSet, 'terms')
router.register(r'disciplines', views.DisciplineViewSet, 'disciplines')
```

As a side note, your should probably exclude `get_` prefix in your urls since that is not RESTful. Each URL should specify a resource, not an action on the resource. Thats what HTTP verbs are used for:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/vocabs/

# or this to create resource
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/vocabs/

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.You are right. In fact the http request already provide that information.

Comment: Doesn't help for me.

Comment: @mirek, if you're using VIewSet you can define the `create` method to handle POST request. Take a look in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901823/post-request-handling-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

Here some more information about router:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Here exist two mandatory arguments for register() method:

> prefix  : The URL prefix to use for this set of routes.
>
> viewset : The viewset class.

And what abut base_name?

The base to use for the URL names that are created. if you don't set the base_name, it will be automatically generated according to the model or queryset attribute on the viewset.

Here is the **URL** patterns generated by example above:

> **URL pattern**: ^users/$ **Name**: 'user-list'

> **URL pattern**: ^users/{pk}/$ **Name**: 'user-detail'

> **URL pattern**: ^accounts/$ **Name**: 'account-list'

> **URL pattern**: ^accounts/{pk}/$ **Name**: 'account-detail'

Now if you want create custome route you should write methods on the viewset decorated with **@link** or **@action** like this:

```
@action(permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
...
```

The following URL generated:

> **URL pattern**: ^users/{pk}/set_password/$ **Name**: 'user-set-password'

You used the DefaultRouter and this router is similar to SimpleRouter, but additionally includes a default API root view, that returns a response containing hyperlinks to all the list views.  It also generates routes for optional .json style format suffixes.

> [See this picture of detail table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mNtw.jpg)

In previous answer you got the right answer .. me just have given you some more information about router

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an answer or comment (or a question).

In my case I have two endpoints to a single model and @miki725 answer was not help for me. I was forced to use separated views and separated serializers.

In `urls.py` I have the 3rd parameter (like @miki725 suggests)

```
router.register(r'doc_v1', views.DocV1ViewSet, basename='doc_v1')
router.register(r'doc_v2', views.DocV2ViewSet, basename='doc_v2')
```

But this is not enough. I must use a separated serializers and connect them to the proper detail view via explicitly defined `url` field:

```
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='doc_v1-detail')
```

This is a pain, because (sometimes) both views differ in really minor details like access permissions are. And I have to make almost identical duplicates of view and serializer.

Not good behavior but I have no other solution for now.