# Post request handling in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, httprequest, django-rest-viewsets

I am using Django Rest Framework, currently to pull some data from the backend we are using Get request, but due to URL limit going high we are planning to implement a Post request. To do this firstly the backend Django Rest API has to be made available to serve a post request.

I am new to Django and I don't find a post or get method in the code, all i can say is we are using viewsets, I tried using "@detail_route(methods=['post'])" but this didn't work, what am I doing wrong here?

```
class XViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    renderer_classes = ''

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            pk = int(pk)
        except ValueError:
            raise InvalidParameterError(parameter_name='id', invalid_value=pk)

        queryset = models.X.objects.all()
        x = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)

        pipelines = request.query_params.getlist('pipeline[]')

        callsets =

        callset_ids =

        serializer = serializers.XSerializer(x, context={'request': request})

        requested_samples = [z[1:] for z in request.query_params.getlist('s')]

        filtered_calls = []
        serialized_data = serializer.data

        unfiltered_calls = serialized_data.get('calls')
        if unfiltered_calls:
            for serialized_calls in unfiltered_calls:
                if serialized_calls['callset'] in callset_ids:
                    unfiltered_calls = serialized_calls['data']

                    for call in unfiltered_calls:
                        if call['y'] in requested_y:
                            filtered_calls.append(call)

                    break

        serialized_data['calls'] = filtered_calls

        return Response(serialized_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def list(self, request):

        qp = self.request.query_params

        validated_qp =

        # generate the query
        query_object =
        query =

        # execute the query
        cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)

        qs = utils.dictfetchall(cursor)

        # sanitize query results
        if 't' in validated_qp:
            return_data =
        else:
            for x in qs:
                if 'calls' in x:

                    x['calls'] =
                else:
                    x['calls'] = {}

            return_data =

        resp = Response(return_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        if validated_qp.get(''):
            resp['content-disposition'] =

        return resp
```

Comment: Show your views as example.

Comment: Please provide an example and show us how and where your method is failing.

Comment: updated with code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [class-based views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) to handle the requirements,

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class MyAPI(APIView):
    def get(selfself, request):
        # do stuff with get
        return Response(data="return msg or data")

    def post(self, request):
        post_data = request.data
        # do something with `post_data`
        return Response(data="return msg or data")
```

**UPDATE : Using ViewSet**

`ViewSet` class provide us `create()` methode to create new model instances. So we can override that to handle post data coming to the view. Just add a `create()` under your view class as below

```
class XViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    renderer_classes = ''

    def create(self, request): # Here is the new update comes <<<<
        post_data = request.data
        # do something with post data
        return Response(data="return data")

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # your code

        return Response(serialized_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def list(self, request):
        # your code
        return resp
```

Comment: As said how can I implement a post method if I use viewsets not APIViews.

Comment: @RealHead Updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: Exactly what I asked for. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if I send parameters in the body of the post request, how can i access them in the backend? Does request.data provide this data?

Comment: Yes. `request.data` holds the whole content. Just use `print()` to verify that

Comment: But `response.data` throws exception `django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`

Comment: @Yougesh Did I mention `response.data` in my answer?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge sorry its `request.data`, typo mistake, but I have resolved that, that issue occurred because of debug point, anyway thanks