# ViewSets not Showing on DjangoRestFramework Despite Being Added on urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a Django project and am trying to add an application's viewset to the project's urls.py. I have already done it for many of my applications, but for some reason, I cannot view this one in my urls.py or my Djangorestframework viewer. I am struggling to understand why this is occurring.

```
class EmailViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A ViewSet for sending emails based on a template.
    """
    serializer_class = EmailTemplateSerializer
    queryset = EmailTemplate.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return EmailTemplate.objects.all()
```

urls.py for project

```
...
router.register(r'profiles', ProfileViewSet, 'profile')
router.register(r'emails', EmailViewSet, 'email')
```

I can see my model in the admin panel but not in the DRF view.

I have tried to change the viewset and add it directly, but I cannot seem to understand or see how I can get it to show up.

Comment: GenericViewSet`.

Comment: How did you register the `router`?

Comment: router = routers.DefaultRouter() 

This worked for all of my other models but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

[for more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291072/django-rest-framework-router-register)

```
router.register(r'profiles', views.ProfileViewSet,'profile')
router.register(r'emails', views.EmailViewSet, 'email')
```

> When you pass URLs that time write URLs like -->views.(class name)